# Open a link in a new window in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

I want to open a link in a new window using reStucturedText. Is this possible?

This opens link in the same window:

```
You can `check your location here. <http://geoiptool.com>`_
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To open a page in a new window or tag you can add the attribute `target="_blank"` to your hyperlink although I'm not sure how you can add attributes to inline hyperlinks in reStructuredText. However, from the Docutils FAQ, [is nested inline markup possible](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible), you can use the `raw` directive to include raw HTML into your document, for example

```
You can |location_link|.

.. |location_link| raw:: html

   <a href="http://geoiptool.com" target="_blank">check your location here</a>
```

#### Update to address comments

I've had the question "why does reStructuredText not have [*insert some awesome feature*]".

In this case, "why does reStructuredText not have a way to specify how links are opened" — I think reStructuredText doesn't have an easy way of doing this since the behaviour of how clicking a link works isn't really it's responsibility. reStructuredText transforms markup — how that markup is ultimately displayed is not up to reStructuredText, but whatever browser or viewer the user chooses to use.

In the case of opening a link in a web browser, good useability practice dictates that you should not force a user to open a link in a new tab (which is what adding `target="_blank"` is doing). Rather, you should leave the choice of how to open the link up to the user. If a user wants to open a link in a new tab, then they can use their middle mouse button (or whatever their favourite shortcut key is).

So I think that it is perfectly acceptable that reStructureText does not have an easy `target="_blank"` feature. The fact that it is possible is nice for people who *really* want to do this is good, and the fact that it is a bit of pain to do so is good for discouraging this practice.

Comment: Nice answer. Seems odd that reStructuredText would not have a simpler way to do this, but what do I know...  Thanks for this; it worked like a charm for a system like http://www.readthedocs.org documentation.

Comment: It does seem odd given that I typically want links to open in a new tab.

Comment: @nueverest I've address your comment and a previous comment in a n update to my answer. The TL;DR is that you can open links in a new tab, but you don't have to enforce this in your markup.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable, what about other kinds of attributes?  :-/  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13168702/450917

Comment: @nicorellius It rather seems odd to want to dictate if links open in a new tab. That's a user decision.

Answer (score 11):

Similar to [Ivonet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733265/2192488), but **without modifying the theme:**

First, install `sphinxcontrib-jquery`:

```bash
$ pip install sphinxcontrib-jquery
```

Then, edit the `conf.py` file as follows:

```py
extensions = [
    …
    'sphinxcontrib.jquery',
]

html_js_files = [
    'js/custom.js'
]
```

Finally ,add a `custom.js` file to the `_static/js` folder:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"]').not('a[class*=internal]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

This shorter version also works with JQuery nowadays:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.external').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I agree completely with the accepted answer, especially with the part where reStructuredText is not responsible for how a link behaves.

I still want it though so it should be solved in the theme. As I want all my external links to open in a new tab it becomes very cumbersome to do it as described above.

In my case I use a third party theme (sphinx_rtd_theme) and I put the following script near the end of the layout.html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Adds target=_blank to external links -->

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"]').not('a[class*=internal]').attr('target', '_blank');
    });
  </script>
```

It seems to do the job just fine.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you also need to refer to the links in other structures, e.g., as targets in figures.

Comment: This breaks basic browser behavior. You should almost never use this convention. The user agent and its user should be in charge of if & when new tabs/windows should be open and developers should respect the defaults.

Comment: As the owner of my site, I am completely within my rights to decide how it should behave. But let's agree to disagree as this is not the place to fight over such things. I just gave a working answer to a question...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you should use JavaScript to set `target="_blank"` for each external links.

See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1634

Answer (score -1):

Tangential to the topic, there are a [lot of reasons](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/) to not use `_target="blank"`. There’s a very high chance you don’t actually want to override the default user agent behavior behavior given that most folks would be using reStructuredText to generate static content.