# How to add rel attribute to docutils sphinx reference in HTML output?

Tags: html, hyperlink, python-sphinx, docutils

I have a simple extension for the Sphinx documentation utility (my version in use isSphinx-1.1.3-py2.6). Very much like [this](https://doughellmann.com/posts/defining-custom-roles-in-sphinx/) excellent example by Doug Hellmann. How can I add a `rel='bar'` attribute to the final HTML for the `<a ...>` tag?

The reference nodes are created in this fashion:

```
node = nodes.reference(rawtext, utils.unescape(text),
            internal=False,
            refuri=ref,
            classes=['foocss'],
            rel='bar',
            **options)
```

However, the `rel='bar'` attribute gets stripped out from the final HTML markup. Hunting through the source got me to `sphinx/writers/html.py` and the `HTMLTranslator` class. Here is part of the visit_reference method:

```
# overwritten
def visit_reference(self, node):
    atts = {'class': 'reference'}
    
    <snip>

    if 'reftitle' in node:
        atts['title'] = node['reftitle']
    self.body.append(self.starttag(node, 'a', '', **atts))
```

Additional attributes are not handled. Maybe they could be replaced in others parts. I couldn't find anything useful in that respect.

So, I could:

- create a custom node which re-implements all the functionality of the reference node. A fair bit of work for a small addition.
- Overwrite the `visit_reference` method in `sphinx/writers/html.py`. Quicker, but bad in terms of future Sphinx updates.
- Add the rel attribute with jQuery to the link tag after the fact. Well, not pretty either.

Comment: I have the same issue and think you should submit a patch to sphinx. But overall I see the system is very complicated and confusing. It took me 3 days of research and I still can't understand how to get conf.py parameters inside a node.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with `download_reference`. Using `app.add_node` I override the `visit_...` method:

```
import posixpath
from sphinx.writers.html import HTMLTranslator
from sphinx.addnodes import download_reference

def visit_download_reference(self, node):
    if node.hasattr('filename'):
        self.body.append(
            '<a class="reference download internal" href="%s" %s>' %
            (posixpath.join(self.builder.dlpath, node['filename']), 'rel="%s"' % node['rel'] if node.get('rel', None) else ''))
        self.context.append('</a>')
    else:
        self.context.append('')

def setup(app):
    app.add_node(download_reference, html=(visit_download_reference, HTMLTranslator.depart_download_reference))
```

[full extension is here](http://pastebin.com/pMhKnTkv)