# Open-in-new-tab link in Sphinx/reST

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there any way to have links open in a new tab in Sphinx/reStructuredText? What in HTML would be target="_blank"?

The only reference I could find is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/NnZVh2X79co), but with no answer.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716781/open-a-link-in-a-new-window-in-restructuredtext