# How to open the original image (not link) in the new tab by default in Sphinx/Markdown

Tags: html, markdown, python-sphinx

I know in sphinx, you can insert your image like that:

````
```{image} diagrams/xxxxx
:alt: xxxxx
:width: 800px
:align: center
````

And I know, as default, if you click your image, sphinx will open the original picture but in the current tab. And you can disable it by add `:class: no-scaled-link`
And also I know, everyone can click the middle button to open a link in a new tab.

But there is a requirement, to left click the image and show the origin in the new tab. I have no idea how to do it.

I already read some similar topic: [Add open-in-new-tab links in Sphinx/reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583581/add-open-in-new-tab-links-in-sphinx-restructuredtext)

I don't think it could help me because it is about the `link` not `image`.