# Sphinx: creating an external link that opens in a new window

Tags: hyperlink, external, python-sphinx

I'm trying to create a link in Sphinx that will open in a new window.

It's within a  .. note::

`<a href="https://bla.bla.bla@sample.com" target="_blank">bla</a>`

Answer (score -1):

I did a second search today and found my question was already answered here.

[Open a link in a new window in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716781/open-a-link-in-a-new-window-in-restructuredtext)

It's possible to do it, but:
 a. its not suggested
 b. it's a bit more difficult to implement